# Debugging a Boolean Loop Statement That Sometimes Works

Tags: java, for-loop, debugging, boolean

I am learning to code in Java, and I am struggling with problems that require boolean variables. Of note - no, this is not homework. I am teaching myself.

The problem I am encountering is that sometimes my code for this problem works, other times, it doesn't. I put the problem into NetBeans to check if I had any syntax errors, and I couldn't find any, so I am hoping someone can better illustrate how the code should be written.

The textbook question:
Declare a Boolean variable named allValid. Then, read integer numInts from input representing the number of integers to be read next. Use a loop to read the remaining integers from input. If all of the numInts integers are in the range 1 to 10 inclusive, assign allValid with true. Otherwise, assign allValid with false.

Code at the end of main() outputs "All valid" if allValid is true or "Has non-matching value(s)" if allValid is false.

Ex: If the input is:

2
5 20
then the output is:

### Has non-matching value(s)

Textbook problem with my answer (the code I have written is between where I have placed a row of asteriks):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntegerData {
public static void main(String [] args) {
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

int numInts;
****************My code starts****************
boolean allValid = true;
int newInput;
int i;
  
numInts = scnr.nextInt();
  
for(i=0; i<numInts; ++i) {
newInput = scnr.nextInt();
  
if (((newInput > 0) && (newInput < 11))) {
allValid = true;
}
  
else {
allValid = false;
}
}
**************My code ends********************        
if (allValid) {
System.out.println("All valid");
}

else {
System.out.println("Has non-matching value(s)");
}
}
}
```

---

---

The following numbers work, for example: 11, -2, 5, 12, -1, 14 (outputs "Has non-matching value(s)"
The following numbers do NOT work, for example: 6, 2, 12, 4, 9 (outputs "All Valid")

And no, it has nothing to do with it being >10, versus <0 because negative numbers sometimes get an incorrect output, too.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently reaching a false value, then continuing to the next loop iteration, which will overwrite the previous value of your `allValid` effectively making only the final result of your loop matter.

Instead you can set `allValid` to `true` as the initial value, and then set it to `false` it ever reaches a value that is not valid. You do not need to ever set `allValid` back to true as once it fails, it should stay failed.

Here a look at the modified code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numInts = scnr.nextInt();

    boolean allValid = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < numInts; i++) {
        int newInput = scnr.nextInt();
        // Any value lower than 1 OR above 10 fails
        if (newInput < 1 || newInput > 10) {
            allValid = false;
        }
    }

    if (allValid) {
        System.out.println("All valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Has non-matching value(s)");
    }
}
```

Note: I also made minor changes such as only declaring variables in the scope they are required.

Test Runs:

```
4
-1 2 3 4
Has non-matching value(s)

6
4 8 3 9 9 1
All valid
```

Answer (score 0):

You gave 2, 5, 20 as a problematic input. 20 is greater than 10. `(20 < 11)` is false. Also, you shouldn't need so many parenthesis. This should work:

```java
if (newInput > 0 && newInput < 11) {
allValid = true;
}
```

Comment: that does not change anything but readability

Comment: Which is important.

Comment: important, but not an **answer** to the question :-/  -  and "*This should work*" is just wrong - it is changing nothing - actually that assignment is exactly the problem of the question (and indentation also is important)